# Change a legend to map to a different variable in R ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a pyramid plot, a very simplified version of which can be drawn with the code below.

```
#sample data
c <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
g <- c("Group A","Group A","Group A","Group B","Group B","Group B")
v <- c(22,34,56,12,44,21)
df <- data.frame(c,g,v)

# here is the plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+
geom_bar(aes(fill=g,y=v,x=c), stat="identity", data=subset(df,g=="Group A"), 
width=0.8)+
geom_bar(aes(fill=g,y=-v,x=c), stat="identity", data=subset(df,g=="Group B"), 
width=0.8)+
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-50,50,10),labels=abs(seq(-50,50,10)))+
coord_flip()
```

It is not a traditional pyramid plot with proportions of population in agegroups, but I do have a good reason for visualizing my data in this way.
Now here is the problem, the two populations I am comparing on the left and right side of the plot I plan to label clearly with annotations in the plot. 
This is one of a series of similar plots and one population will always be on the right and the other on the left (g in my example). The issue with this plot is that the categories ('c' in this example) have long descriptive names and are best numbered off with a legend saying what they are.

So what I want is a plot that looks like this but has a legend indicating the categories and their descriptors (e.g. '1: Elementary', '2:
Intermediate', '3: Advanced' etc) which relate to the 'c' variable rather than the default based on my two population groups. BTW, in my actual plot I have thirteen bars representing thirteen different categories rather than the three I have here.

I've tried using scale_color_manual and setting the aesthetic argument to the c variable, which seemed logical (to me anyway!) but this does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your categories to be a character or a factor you can then map that variable to a new aesthetic such as `color`

```
c=(c("1 - Elementary","2 - Intermediate","3 - Advanced","1 - Elementary","2 - Intermediate", "3 - Advanced"))
g=c("Group A","Group A","Group A","Group B","Group B","Group B")
v=as.numeric(c(22,34,56,12,44,21))
df<-data.frame(c,g,v)

# here is the plot

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=g,y=v,x=c, color = c), stat="identity",data=subset(df,g=="Group A"), 
           width=0.8)+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=g,y=-v,x=c, color = c),stat="identity",data=subset(df,g=="Group B"), 
           width=0.8)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-50,50,10),labels=abs(seq(-50,50,10))) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

You can also just forego the extra aesthetic and simply allow the axis to inform the reader which group is which:

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=g,y=v,x=c), stat="identity",data=subset(df,g=="Group A"), 
           width=0.8)+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=g,y=-v,x=c),stat="identity",data=subset(df,g=="Group B"), 
           width=0.8)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-50,50,10),labels=abs(seq(-50,50,10))) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: OK that has helpfully clarified the use of the color argument for me. So if I were to only use the legend for c, how would I not show the other one in the final plot?

Comment: Add the line `+ theme(legend.position = "none")`. Would you like me to update my post?

Comment: No that's fine thanks, I was just playing around with guides and also got there.  The critical issue was I had the problem as I did not understand the use of color and I do now as a result of your answer. Thanks.